# What are some DMRG packages with an easy learning curve?

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, software-recommendations, high-performance-computing, dmrg

I've been meaning to learn how to use DMRG (density matrix renormalization group) for a long time. Which packages have an easy learning curve? I specifically mean it should be easy to actually learn how to write your **own** calculations that do nontrivial things, **not** just run an example code that they provide.

Edit: I want to do calculations on spin systems or lattice bosons/fermions. Heisenberg or Hubbard-like models.

Comment: +1. Can you specify what the calculation is for? I think the answer will vary greatly depending on whether you want to do quantum chemistry, or explore some model Hamiltonian, or to do something else.

Comment: I want to do calculations on spin systems or perhaps lattice bosons/fermions.

Comment: What kind of calculations though? Are you looking for zero or finite temperature properties? Are you looking for simple observables like energy and magnetization, or entanglement properties, correlation functions? Perhaps even dynamical correlation functions? Are the systems homogeneous or not?

Comment: @Anyon, let's say I want to have the option to do as many of those things as possible. My goal here is to start with a tool that is both powerful and easy to use.

Comment: This has remained in the unanswered queue for quite a while! Are there any DMRG codes that you have used for spin systems or lattice bosons/fermions? Which ones?

Comment: I think I would be most interested in lattice spins with Heisenberg-like interactions. It would be great to get an answer comparing, for example, ALPS, OpenMPS, ITensor.

Comment: Here's list of some packages for tensor network calculations: (https://tensornetwork.org/software/) .  I found TenPy to be useful.